# Writeable streams in Node?

Tags: node.js

In NodeJS, when a stream is writeable `mystream.writeable = true`, does  that mean that this stream can write things, or does that mean it can be written to?

Comment: Writeable streams can be written to.  Readable streams can be read from.

Comment: @generalhenry, this is not obvious to non-native English speakers, you should add that as an answer